# input file being read with weird characters

Tags: c

I have this function here, that reads a file in the format of:

```
(badgeno)
(name)
(location) // until it hits *
(birthday)
```

I added a record into the txt file like so through the program:
Note: I checked the file after closing the program and it was written exactly like this before I opened the program again.

```
5432
Janna Wind
3321 Jupiter St
44324, Fi, CA
*
1990
```

However, when I open the program and I print the record it shows up like:

```
5432
Janna Wind
!34^&32()93321 Jupiter St
44324, Fi, CA
1990
```

And when I check the txt file I stored it into after closing the program, it looked like this:

```
5432
Janna Wind
!34^&32()93321 Jupiter St
44324, Fi, CA
*
1990
```

I'm assuming there must be something wrong with my 'while(fgets...' for the location but I can't figure out why. Weird characters means its reading data from an address that I didn't assign or something like that right? I'm sorry if I sound confusing.

```
int readfile(struct test ** start, char filename[]){

FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(filename,"r");

int badgeno;
char fullname[45];
char location[100];
int birthday;
char line[80];
int opened = 1;

if (fp == NULL){

    opened = 1;

} else {

    opened = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &badgeno) > 0) {

        fgets(fullname, 45, fp);

        strncpy(location, line, sizeof(line));

        while (fgets(line, 80, fp)) {
            if (strcmp(line, "*\n") == 0) {
                line[0] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            strncat(location, line, 79 - strlen(location));
        }

        fscanf(fp, "%d[^\n]", &birthday);

        addRecord(start, badgeno, fullname, location, birthday);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
return opened;
}
```

I know my code is messy, so please excuse me. But yeah, what could possibly be causing these weird characters to show up when I re-open the program again. Is it likely that my fgets line is the problem in the code?

Comment: "I know my code is messy, so please excuse me." You know it is messy, then fix it, do not apologize.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%d[^\n]", &birthday);` → `fscanf(fp, "%d", &birthday);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
strncpy(location, line, sizeof(line));
```

With this line you copy from the (*uninitialized!*) array `line` into `location`. Because `line` is uninitialized its contents is *indeterminate* and you will get *undefined behavior*.

Instead you should just "clear" the `location` array so you can append to it later in the loop. This is easiest done when defining the `location` array:

```
char location[100] = { 0 };
```

That will set all elements of `location` to zero, which is the string terminator.

Comment: I thought so! Should I use another function besides this? My goal was to actually wipe the array so that it doesn't hold previous data.